# Resharper variable name completion not working

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-8.1

I have upgrade resharper version with following details:

> JetBrains ReSharper 8.1 C# Edition Build 8.1.23.546 on
>   2013-12-12T08:30:52

I remember this used to work in previous version but since I upgraded to 8.1 I am missing this feature. Basically I am talking about resharper suggestion for auto variable name completion.

[image]

Is it just disable or removed? If disabled by default how can I enable it?

Comment: I have exactly that version, and it's working for me. Maybe close VStudio, clean project (delete any temp files) and restart? And you are editing the code from the project that contains it? (You're not accidentally editing that file from a different project, for example?)

Comment: Oh yes it's my bad. I had turned off intelliSense. I think some time ago while selecting keyboard scheme. Its fixed now. Thank for suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

> ReSharper -> Options -> IntelliSense -> Completion Behavior

Here you can get the setting to enable/disable the auto completion.

Mark that you have the option to specify, after how many character, the auto completion is thrown.

Comment: Due to your suggestion I discovered I had turned off intelliSense. I think some time ago while selecting keyboard scheme. Its fixed now. Thank for answer.